# How to assign graphics performance preferences to Windows 10 programs FOR ALL USERS?

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card

As shown [here](https://www.ghacks.net/2018/11/30/assign-graphics-performance-preferences-windows-10-programs/), I can assign graphics performance preferences to Windows 10 programs.

However, I have to replicate all the steps, for each user in my Windows 10.

How could I do a global setting for all users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this setting creates values under the registry key:
`HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DirectX\UserGpuPreferences`
[image]

Not sure when the key is queried.

There doesn't seem to be a corresponding key under `HKLM`, so your best bet may be to copy the key to every user.